# Pubnub: Channel quota exceeded

Tags: java, pubnub

I am using pubnub Java SDK 3.7.2. I use free plan only.
When I publish bunch of messages without stopping, I often get the following error. But I publish a message every 200-300 milliseconds, the error does not happen. Is there any restriction on an interval of publishing?

```
[Error: 127-0] : Bad request. Please contact support with error details. : [0,"Channel quota exceeded (2/1000000)","14219273229924875"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: The same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416918/throttle-pubnub-publish-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yohei, this most likely means you are using the demo pub/sub keys and not your own pub/sub keys.

Comment: Beautiful! Glad it worked out for you. We throttle the demo keys so they are not abused. All of your own keys are not throttled.

Comment: great! thats exactly was my problem, maybe the error message should appoint this

Comment: We get very little feedback (like once a year) about it. Most just don't use the demo for more than a few minutes before getting their own keys.